# Can somebody explain how gunicorn handles SIGTERM or SIGINT signals

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals, gunicorn

I run application via gunicorn with single worker.
So, I have main process (let say, wth id=12). Also I can create another process from main using multiprocessing (id = 20, whatever).
Also I want to provide possibility to interrupt child process (with id=20). To achieve this, from main process call `os.kill(20, signal.SIGTERM)`. Also, custom handler for `SIGTERM` signal provided.

The problem is, that if application catches the signal, process (id=20) stopped as I expected, but also main process stopped after, too. And worker restarts.

The docs (https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/signals.html#master-process) pretty poor or maybe I something missed.

I've playing around for a while and realized that I can stop child process via `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2` without worker restarting (of course, if my custom method provided for this signals).

But I'm not sure, is it correct way to stop process. Or maybe I can do same with `SIGTERM`, somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Were you forking (using multiprocessing) a gunicorn worker, or somehow the master process? Could you write a minimal code example? A lot of what is happening depends on what and where you fork, where do you install the signal handlers, who signals who and so on.